# how to merge custom class arrays in java to be sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How do you sort two custom array classes that have a parent/child relationship? The sorting needs to be based on a String variable that is in the parent class and the sorting has to happen for both classes without displaying the sorted values of one class then the sorted values of the other class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Store {

    // main method begins execution of program
    public static void main (String [] agrs) {
    //code...

    Book[] bk = new Book[3];
    Movie[] movie = new Movie[2];
    //code...
}

class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    private String title;
    //code...
@Override

public int compareTo(Book o) {
    if(o == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (this == o) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if(this.title != null && o.title != null) {
            return this.title.compareTo(o.title);
        }
        else if(this.title != null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }}}}
class Movie extends Book {
    private String diskType;
```

How would you sort these two classes at the same time so that they both would be displayed alphabetically based on the title variable in the Book class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is by combining the two arrays into one, then sorting the combined array:

```
ArrayList<Book> combinedList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(bk));
combinedList.addAll(Arrays.asList(movie));
Collections.sort(combinedList);
```

Because you already have `Comparable<Book>` implemented, there shouldn't be anything else you need to do to do this.

If you can't use `ArrayList`, then you'll have to combine the arrays into a single array yourself before sorting. This can be done pretty easily:

```
1. Create an array with size equal to the combined size of the smaller arrays
2. Copy one array in
3. Copy the other array in, starting where the first left off (or starting from the other end)
4. `Arrays.sort()`
```

Comment: Is there any other way besides using an ArrayList?

Comment: Well, the thing is if you want to sort both arrays as if they were two parts of the same array you're going to have to combine them in some way. Unless I'm misinterpreting what you want to do?

Comment: Yes I do want to sort both them as two parts of the same array.

Comment: Yeah, in that case you'll have to combine them. Using an `ArrayList` is the easiest way, but if you really want to you can do the combining manually.

Comment: Just cant use ArrayList for this assignment. I understand if you don't want to give me the answer to it, all I'm really looking for is an example of how to do it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `Arrays.sort()`? Or do you have to write your own sorting method?

Comment: Check my answer. I left it in regular English because implementation should be quite easy, but if you have a specific problem feel free to ask

Comment: System.arraycopy(bk, 0, temp, 0, bk.length);
System.arraycopy(movie, 0, temp, temp.length-bk.length, movie.length);
Arrays.sort(temp);

Comment: I think you actually want to start on `bk.length` for the second call; imagine if `bk.length = 6` and `movie.length = 8`. Your way would start copying at `8` for the second call, which would lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: But otherwise I think that's it!

Comment: In the 2nd arraycopy if I use (movie, 0, temp.length-movie.length, movie.length) I get only 3 out of the 5 arrays displaying. 1 from the movie array and 2 from book array. Book is an array of 3 and movie is an array of 2. But if I replace temp.length-movie.length with temp.length-bk.length I get a NullPointerException What am I do wrong that its not copying all the arrays over?

Comment: No, I wasn't saying replace `temp.length - movie.length` with `temp.length - bk.length`; I was saying to use *just* `bk.length`. The `NullPointerException` is likely because you're passing in a `null` reference for one of the arrays. Are all the arrays you're adding in initialized?

Comment: These are my initialized arrays Book[] bk = new Book[3];
 Movie[] movie = new Movie[2];
 Book[] temp = new Book[bk.length + movie.length];

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Try using a debugger to step through and inspecting variables to see whether they are null. Or put in `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(<array name>));` to print contents of each array. The print that throws an exception is your `null` array.

Comment: i found my problem I had a for loop that when I printed the results. It was based on movie.length instead of temp.length I thought if you did a regular println it would only print one variable of the array. Guess I need to study up on it a little more & thank for all the help.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad to know I could help!